# If TeX is a programming language, how could I start programming in TeX?

Tags: latex

I use a Mac. But I also have a PC with Windows 7. So when I want to start programming functionality for LaTeX using TeX, what's my starting point? Is there an SDK and documentation? I couldn't find any book on TeX programming.

Comment: 7 very similar questions in the last hour.  May I suggest google?

Comment: It might be unclear what you mean with "programming in TeX". If you mean "general purpose programming" (i.e., making a nice Windows picture slicer with GUI), you shouldn't consider TeX at all. If you mean to program to create books or white papers, by all means, it's a good choice. There's ample documentation. SDK is not relevant.

Comment: If google is hard, here's a helpful link: http://www.google.com/search?q=tex+programming&lr=&btnG=Google+zoeken or try Wikibooks TeX for the Impatient: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX_for_the_Impatient or just Wiki[pedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX. For books, just type "TeX" or "LaTeX" in the search box of Amazon.com, this finds http://www.amazon.com/Beginners-Book-TEX-Raymond-Seroul/dp/0387975624/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1261179408&sr=8-3 or Knuth's well-known  http://www.amazon.com/TeXbook-Donald-E-Knuth/dp/0201134489/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_b

Comment: you might want to look at ConTeXt. You can, more or less, set-up your page layout from scratch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the starting point to write functionality for LaTeX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931109/whats-the-starting-point-to-write-functionality-for-latex)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Programming something in TeX that isn't a document:

- [A BASIC interpreter](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/basix?lang=en)
- [The Mars rover](http://sdh33b.blogspot.com/2008/07/icfp-contest-2008.html)

So it can be done — it's just an exercise in esoteric, obfuscated programming.

Comment: The basic interpreter link seems to be broken.

Comment: @awllower, I fixed the link.

Answer (score 10):

Read Don Knuth's [*The TeXbook*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201134489)—everything you wanted to know about programming TeX, straight from the source.  My favorite chapter is Appendix D: Dirty Tricks.

(Michael Plass, who was Don's student and worked with Don on TeX, told me once that "Don tried very hard not to make TeX a programming language.  Unfortunately, he didn't succeed.")

Answer (score 4):

To quote [Eric Raymond](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch08s03.html):

> TeX is intentionally Turing-complete (it has conditionals, loops, and recursion), but while it can be made to do amazing things, TeX code tends to be unreadable and painful to debug.

He goes on to say that even if it's possible to program in TeX, it's a really bad idea.

Comment: What's the definition of "to program in TeX"? If you use it for making nice documents, it is rather easy, readable and no problem at all. In a day you have learned how to make PDFs or DVI documents, programmed using TeX.

Comment: It's a bit of a joke, Tex is a text layout language, but since it has loops and conditions you can program in it. But really this is only done for fun

Comment: Huh? There's a whole bunch of programming (in the form of LaTeX packages) that has been done over the years. It (the programming) is a little restrictive but it's certainly done for practical purposes.

Comment: I guess unintentionally Turing-complete languages are way funnier.

Answer (score 4):

TeX and LaTeX (its follow-up) are quite old languages nowadays, but are still widespread and often used. Their primary use is found in universities, specifically with mathematics and natural sciences. It's not a programming language like C#, PHP or JavaScript, it's more a document-layout language (a bit like HTML perhaps, without any of the modern events).

The idea behind TeX was to use the computer to calculate how the text would be best laid out on the paper when you print it. That means that in TeX, you lay out a table, but you don't say anything (or little) about its size. The TeX compiler will take care of that.

When it comes to books or sites, there's a sheer many of them. Try amazon, for instance this [Guide To LaTeX](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321173856).

Forget about TeX, use LaTeX. It's the same, it's easier, and it's more widespread. LaTeX is TeX. But TeX is not LaTeX.

Comment: @qaher, since TeX is Turing Complete, has if then else and recursion, and is used to program page layout, I think you can safely call it a programming language. LaTeX on the other hand primarily consists of macros for TeX, perhaps that's what you meant?

Comment: Yes, of course, the TeX itself is a “typesetting system” in which a turing-complete language is included, while the mentioned programming language itself doesn’t have a unique name assigned, it really adds to the ambiguity that the TeX is “also” a programming language.

Answer (score 4):

Let me suggest Prof. Knuth's site:
[link text](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/abcde.html)

There are all the books you would want to have on TeX.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try starting out with the `expl3` programming language, which is a layer on top of TeX with more consistent syntax, more abstracted data structures, and quite a deal more in-built functionality for performing programmatic tasks than LaTeX's kernel. Disclaimer: I'm involved with its development.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the other good answers, as TeX is a typesetting system there are not IDEs in that sense. There are lots of TeX aware editors (I use TeXworks, but Emacs is obviously a popular choice particularly on Linux, whole TeXniccenter is very common on Windows).

Answer (score 2):

if you ever need to write an essay or a paper or anything that you want to look nice and publishable, LaTeX is definitely your friend. I recommend More Math into LaTeX as that book really helped me in the past. [Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) also has an excellent LaTeX guide (on top of being free!).

If you're familiar with Eclipse IDE already then the TeXlipse plugin is great for beginners since it can show user immediate feedback and documentation.

Comment: Eclipse IDE is a big elephant, you should use it only if you have a lot of available resources.
I would suggest you try TexStudio. It's a lot lighter, open source and just like Eclipse it has function completion. Moreover, it has a spell checker that works while you type.